# How to upload Archives for several modules by using gradle?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to publish my SDK in maven with `$ ./gradlew uploadArchives`

I had this project structure:

```
MyProject

  |_ SDK
     |_ src
         |_ main
              |_ java
                   |_ java files
     |_ build.gradle
  |_ gradle
        |_ gradle-publish.gradle
```

I used following code (`gradle-publish.gradle`) that works as expected:

```
task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
         /* ... */
        }
    }
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
}
```

---

Now I splitted main module to 2: `SDK` and `new_module` so my project structure looks like:

```
MyProject

  |_ SDK
     |_ src
         |_ main
              |_ java
                   |_ java files  "com.app"
     |_ build.gradle

 |_ new_module
     |_ src
         |_ main
              |_ java
                   |_ java files "com.app.mod"
      |_ build.gradle
  |_ gradle
        |_ gradle-publish.gradle
```

However no matter what I do, I always get only `SDK` sources and not `new_module` a.e. `com.app` should be merged with `com.app.mod`

I tried to play with `sourceSets` but it looks like it works inside main module `SDK` and not under root project:

```
sourceSets {
    main{
      java {
        srcDirs(
                "src/main/java",
                 "../new_module/src/main/java"
        )
    }
}
```

and:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
   classifier = 'sources'   
   from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs    
}
```

Any ideas, tips?

**Edit**

I added

```
sourceSets {
    main{
      java {

        srcDirs("src/main/java",
                "${root_dir}/new_module/src/main/java"
        )
      }
    }
  }
```

However on maven I see all have sources but `classes.jar` contains only `app` `.class` files

Comment: then its hard to get answer.

Comment: I believe since they're two different modules, you either need to include JARs when packaging the artifacts for SDK module, or you could upload the two modules separately. The latter would be better since in the former could end up including publicly available library jars which could result with issues for some developers using your library because of duplicate public libs found. Either way, posting your `build.gradle` files for the two modules would give more insight on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add custom `sourceSet` under `android` section of your `SDK` `build.gradle`:

```
android{
    //...
    sourceSets {
        main{
            java {
                srcDirs "$rootDir/new_module/src/main/java/"

            }
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need include `"src/main/java"` - its already included

Also you don't need bind `new_module` into your dependancies, `new_module` will be a part of your `SDK` module

```
task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
  }
```

Comment: After 2 days at last your answer helped me to solve this problem.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Check this [link](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en) it's intended for distribution through Jcenter, follow the steps mentioned in the link for each of your submodules.

And make sure all your submodules are published to the same remote with a common GROUP_ID.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to include your gradle-publish.gradle in each build.gradle? Or alternatively in your main build.gradle?

E.g. in `${rootDir}/new_module/build.gradle`

```
apply from "${rootDir}/gradle/gradle-publish.gradle"
```

Or in `${rootDir}/build.gradle`:

```
subprojects {
  apply from "${rootDir}/gradle/gradle-publish.gradle"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you didn't define the artifacts to publish in your build.gradle:

```
artifacts {
    archives jar, javadocJar, sourcesJar
    testArchives testJar, testSourcesJar
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar) {
    description "Assembles a jar archive containing the javadoc files"

    classifier = "javadoc"
    from javadoc
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    description "Assembles a jar archive containing the source files"

    classifier = "sources"
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task testJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: project.testClasses) {
    description "Assembles a jar archive containing the test files"

    classifier = "test"
    from project.sourceSets.test.output
}

task testSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    description "Assembles a jar archive containing the test source files"

    classifier = "test-sources"
    from sourceSets.test.allSource
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`uploadArchives` isn't meant to be used to install to the local Maven repository. Instead, use the `install` task.

replace this: from

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
         /* ... */
        }
    }
}
```

to :

```
install{
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
             /* ... */
            }
        }
    }
```